# Thunderbird: embedded images not rendering inline

Tags: html, email, thunderbird, inline-images

This may not be the most appropriate place for this, I have posted to the Mozilla boards but I'm guessing SO gets a few more eyeballs... Anyway:

We're generating an HTML email with inline images. They display fine in Outlook 2007, but do not render inline with Thunderbird 2.0.0.23, they show up as attachments. I have the following set in my thunderbird client:

```
Display attachments inline: tick 
Message Body As: Original HTML
```

As far as I can tell the various headers are correct (from Thunderbird  view source):

```
------=_Part_1_9884354.1303120232543 
Content-Type: image/gif; name=classpath_466bd94ae6b_before.gif 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=classpath_466bd94ae6b_before.gif 
Content-ID: <classpath_466bd94ae6b_before.gif>
```

and the HTML (Thunderbird source):

```
<img title=3D"Before" alt=3D"Before" height=3D"13" width=3D"52" src=3D"cid:classpath_466bd94ae6b_before.gif"/>
```

Everything looks good per the docs, any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does it work in other clients like Apple Mail.app, Gmail, etc?

Comment: Apple I don't know, hotmail, gmail yes working fine.

Comment: what are those `3D` chars between the `=` and `"`? artifact of your paste here?

Comment: @Mat - they appear to be an artifact of the Thuderbird source view, I _think_ they can be ignored

Comment: make sure of that (use wget or curl and view with a plain text editor)

Comment: @Mat: Hmmm. Saving as a plain text file these 3D's remain. They exist throughout the HTML, all of which renders fine, except for the missing images. However they are def NOT in what I generate, and don't appear in the source for any of the other clients.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by changing Content-Type: multipart/mixed; to Content-Type: multipart/related; (in the MIME of the constructed email)

Comment: Switching to "Content-Type: multipart/related" worked for me: thanks!